# Getting Inertia.js and Xampp to work together

Tags: laravel, vue.js, xampp, inertiajs

I have tried to set up a project with Laravel, Vue, and Inertia. I am developing on Windows using xampp.

I have configured C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf with the following:

```
<VirtualHost inertia-example.test:80>
  DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/inertia-example/public" 
  <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/inertia-example/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also added an entry to C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

When I go to inertia-example.test all I see is an h1 tag w/ the text "Welcome to Laravel!", which is most assuredly not what's in Welcome.vue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a link (https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel) to the github if that is helpful.

The app.blade.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

@inertia

</body>
</html>
```

The routes file, specifically web.php, is:

```
<?php

use Inertia\Inertia;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    // return view('welcome');
    return Inertia::render('Welcome');
});
```

The Welcome.vue is as follows:

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is the Welcome page!
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you configured your routes? Have you updated your `app.blade.php` as indicated in the repo with `@inertia`?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Can you show your `routes/web.php` and your `app.blade.php`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested.

Comment: Thanks. Have you also installed the [Vue adapter](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-vue) for Inertia? If so, can you also add `Welcome.vue` to the question?

Comment: Yes, that was the first step I did. I have included Welcome.vue, but it's just a basic template.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Are you sure it's calling the right directory? If you put a `dd('Foo Bar');` in your `routes/web.php`, does it show up in your browser?

Comment: This is what I am not sure about. I tried that and got nothing, but then again I'm not entirely sure where it should show up. The entry point of a laravel app is public/index.php, which is why I edited httpd-vhosts.conf as such. That being said, I'm wondering if something with Inertia means it needs to be pointed somewhere else. I'm really not sure because nobody seems to have encountered this problem (as most are developing on Macs).

Comment: Like, where is "Welcome to Laravel!" anywhere in a Laravel app? This is something else that's throwing me off.

Comment: Do you have another project on your machine that is displaying `Welcome to Laravel`? What if you do a global search for that string in all your projects?

Comment: Yes, I can't find that string in the project anywhere, which makes me wonder where it's coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196716/discussion-between-chin-leung-and-user3727648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I was not very far into what I was trying to do, I decided to stop, uninstall XAMPP, install Laragon, and go from there. I just followed the docs and now everything seems to be working. My gut tells me that XAMPP won't work and it has something to do with having to manually configure the httpd-vhosts.conf and etc/hosts files.